# Expression does not evaluate to true despite both conditions being true

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-pipelines

This is what I have for this particular stage:

```
parameters:
- name: services
  type: object
  default:
  - admin
  - admin-v2
  - api
  - client

stages:
- stage: UnitTests
  displayName: Run unit tests on service...
  dependsOn: Changed
  condition: succeeded()
  variables:
    apiChanged: $[ stageDependencies.Changed.Changes.outputs['detectChanges.apiChanged'] ]
  jobs:
  - job: UnitTests
    condition: or(eq(stageDependencies.Changed.Changes.outputs['detectChanges.anyServicesChanged'], true), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'))
    displayName: Running unit tests...
    steps:
    - ${{ each service in parameters.services }}:
      - ${{ if and(eq(service, 'api'), eq(variables.apiChanged, true)) }}:
        - bash: |
            echo "Now running ${{ service }} unit tests..."
```

The line that is in question is:

```
- ${{ if and(eq(service, 'api'), eq(variables.apiChanged, true)) }}:
```

- If it is just the first condition, the subsequent `bash` executes when `service = 'api'`.
- If it is just the second condition, the subsequent `bash` *does not* execute which leads me to believe it comes back `false`.
- Thus, having both conditions it evaluates to `false`.

So the `eq(variables.apiChanged, true)` is obviously the problem.

I have verified that `apiChanged = true` by doing the following:

```
- bash: |
    echo $(apiChanged)
```

I've done this before the `- ${{ each service in parameters.services }}:` and it comes back `true`.

I've also tried `eq(variables.adminV2Changed, true)` and `eq(variables.adminV2Changed, 'true'`).

Any suggestions for why this happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure DevOps, the syntax `${{}}` is for compile time and `$[]` is for runtime expressions. That means that when `${{}}` expressions execute, `$[]` expressions have not yet executed.

In other words, in a compile-time expression, you **only** have access to **parameters** and **statically defined variables**.

In your case, the compile-time expression contains a variable `apiChanged` which needs to be execute. Its value is `$[stageDependencies.Changed.Changes.Outputs['detectChanges. ApiChanged]]` instead of the calculated value `true`.

Comment: So it sounds like what I'm trying to do isn't possible then?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops